# Adding an if statement to a cast for birth date

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have the following code which takes the response (from Facebook) and twists the date around to make it British (day, month, year) rather than American.

I have added a +1 condition for the month, as it starts it at zero.

Now I need to add an if statement that sets **if the month is less than 10**, add 0 to the beginning*. This is because it's currently displaying 1, 2 etc and it needs to be 01, 02.

I'm not sure about how to add this kind of statement in the middle of my existing code?

```
var bday = new Date(response.birthday);
document.getElementById("<%= tbOrg.ClientID %>").value = bday.getDate() + "/" + (bday.getMonth()+1) + "/" + bday.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 fixDays = function (d) {
        var days = d;
        if (parseInt(days) < 10) {
            days = "0" + days;
        }
        return days.toString();
    }
```

Use it like fixDays(bday.getDate);

**Update**

```
document.getElementById("<%= tbOrg.ClientID %>").value = fixDays(bday.getDate()) + "/" + fixDays((bday.getMonth()+1)) + "/" + bday.getFullYear();
```

Comment: `getDate()` returns a number.

Comment: It now outputs the following instead of the date: function getDate() { [native code] }/1/1991 - first of all it's supposed to change the MONTH but it's changed the DAY?

Comment: You need to add the radix (10) to your `parseInt()`

Answer (score 2):

```
var bDate = bday.getDate();
    bDate = bDate < 10 ? '0'+bDate : bDate;
document.getElementById("<%= tbOrg.ClientID %>").value = bDate + "/" + (bday.getMonth()+1) + "/" + bday.getFullYear();​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var getTwoDigitMonth = function(date) {
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    if (month < 10) {
        month = "1" + month;
    }
    return month;
};

var bday = new Date(response.birthday);
var el = document.getElementById("<%= tbOrg.ClientID %>");
el.value = bday.getDay() + "/" + getTwoDigitMonth(bday) + "/" + bday.getFullYear();
```